# Javascript Search multiple fields in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, search

I have the following javascript search function

```
function findMatches(srchFor, srchList, keyobj) {
        return srchList.filter(srchList => {
            const regex = new RegExp(srchFor, 'gi');
            return srchList[keyobj].match(regex);
        });
    }
```

Example Json object to search;

```
    Customers = {"entity": [{
            "Id": "ACB123",
            "OrderId": 0,
            "EntityType": "CU",
            "Name": "ABC Company",
            "Address1": "123 Main Street",
            "Address2": null,
            "City": "CROCKETT",
            "State": "CA",
            "Zip": "94525",
            "Country": "USA",
            "Phone": null,
            "Email": null,
            "Contact": null,
            "IdCodeQual": null,
            "IdCode": null,
            "LastUpdate": "2021-04-06T17:31:02",
            "Attrib01": null,
            "Attrib02": null,
            "Attrib03": null,
            "Attrib04": null,
            "Attrib05": null
        },
        {
            "Id": "WFCH",
            "OrderId": 0,
            "EntityType": "CU",
            "Name": "World's Finest Company",
            "Address1": "100 State Street",
            "Address2": null,
            "City": "Chicago",
            "State": "IL",
            "Zip": "60632",
            "Country": "USA",
            "Phone": "773-555-1200",
            "Email": null,
            "Contact": null,
            "IdCodeQual": null,
            "IdCode": null,
            "LastUpdate": "2016-09-20T12:59:25",
            "Attrib01": null,
            "Attrib02": null,
            "Attrib03": null,
            "Attrib04": null,
            "Attrib05": null
        }
    ]
}
```

This function works fine as is for searching one field with usage as

```
var result = findMatches('ABC',Customers,'Id')
```

What I would like to be able to do is pass in more than one field to search as such

```
var result = findMatches('ABC',Customers,['Id','Name'])
```

so I can search both the name and Id fields for a match without having to have an explicitly defined search.  I'd like the same function to work for

```
var result = findMatches('ABC',Customers,['City','Address1'])
```

Comment: Do you want it to match both fields or either of them? Also, what have you already tried to solve it? It seems like the filter function can simply loop through the array of field names.

Comment: I want to match either or.

Comment: So something like `for (const key of keys) { 
if srchList[key].match(regex) return true;
        } return false;`

Answer (score 2):

This solution filters array depending on several fields

```
const Customers = {
    entity: [
        {
            Id: "ACB123",
            OrderId: 0,
            EntityType: "CU",
            Name: "ABC Company",
            Address1: "123 Main Street",
            Address2: null,
            City: "CROCKETT",
            State: "CA",
            Zip: "94525",
            Country: "USA",
            Phone: null,
            Email: null,
            Contact: null,
            IdCodeQual: null,
            IdCode: null,
            LastUpdate: "2021-04-06T17:31:02",
            Attrib01: null,
            Attrib02: null,
            Attrib03: null,
            Attrib04: null,
            Attrib05: null,
        },
        {
            Id: "WFCH",
            OrderId: 0,
            EntityType: "CU",
            Name: "World's Finest Company",
            Address1: "100 State Street",
            Address2: null,
            City: "Chicago",
            State: "IL",
            Zip: "60632",
            Country: "USA",
            Phone: "773-555-1200",
            Email: null,
            Contact: null,
            IdCodeQual: null,
            IdCode: null,
            LastUpdate: "2016-09-20T12:59:25",
            Attrib01: null,
            Attrib02: null,
            Attrib03: null,
            Attrib04: null,
            Attrib05: null,
        },
    ],
};

//Returns what recieves
const pass = (input) => input;

const findInArray = (array, searchRegExp, fields) => {
    return array.filter((item) => {
        // returs true if at least one of fields value match to regexp
        return fields.map((field) => searchRegExp.test(item[field])).some(pass);
    });
};

console.log(findInArray(Customers.entity, /ACB/, ["Id", "Name"]));
```

Comment: thanks. this worked perfect for me.